# How can I draw text with line on canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

**How can i draw line with text in canvas. Text which shows is length of line that shows with line when it draws on canvas.
Kindly help me out on this situation.

Here is an output images that i tried.
Current Output:
**
[image]

and here's output that i need.
Required Output:
[image]

Here is Drawing View Code that i've tried.

```
    class Line {
    float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
    public Line(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.stopX = stopX;
        this.stopY = stopY;
    }
    public Line(float startX, float startY) { // for convenience
        this(startX, startY, startX, startY);
    }
}

public class DrawView extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    Path path = new Path();
    private void init() {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    }

    private void drawArrow1(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Canvas canvas, Paint paint1) {
        double degree = calculateDegree(startX, stopX, startY, stopY);

        float endX1 = (float) (stopX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree-30)+90))));
        float endY1 = (float) (stopY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree-30)+90)))));

        float endX2 = (float) (stopX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree-60)+180))));
        float endY2 = (float) (stopY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree-60)+180)))));

        canvas.drawLine(stopX,stopY,endX1,endY1,paint1);
        canvas.drawLine(stopX, stopY, endX2,endY2,paint1);
    }

    private void drawArrow(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Canvas canvas, Paint paint1) {

        double degree1 = calculateDegree(stopX, startX, stopY, startY);
        float endX11 = (float) (startX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree1-30)+90))));
        float endY11 = (float) (startY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree1-30)+90)))));

        float endX22 = (float) (startX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree1-60)+180))));
        float endY22 = (float) (startY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree1-60)+180)))));

        canvas.drawLine(startX,startY,endX11,endY11,paint1);
        canvas.drawLine(startX,startY,endX22,endY22,paint1);

    }

    public double calculateDegree(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
        float startRadians = (float) Math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
        System.out.println("radian=====" + Math.toDegrees(startRadians));
        startRadians += ((x2 >= x1) ? 90 : -90) * Math.PI / 180;
        return Math.toDegrees(startRadians);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Line l : lines) {
            canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY, paint);
            drawArrow(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY,canvas,paint);
            drawArrow1(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY,canvas,paint);
        }
    }

    float first_x, first_y, last_x, last_y, line_lenght;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            first_x = x;
            first_y = y;

            lines.add(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            return true;
        }
        else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ||
                event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) &&
                lines.size() > 0) {
            Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
            current.stopX = event.getX();
            current.stopY = event.getY();
            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            line_lenght = (float) Math.pow(Math.abs(first_x-last_x),2) + (float) Math.pow(Math.abs(first_y-last_y),2);
            line_lenght = (float) Math.sqrt(line_lenght);
            Log.i("lenght", String.valueOf(line_lenght));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see how folks draw zigzag in flutter: [paintZigZag](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/paint_utilities.dart#L23) - do the similar trick when drawing a line with arrows

Answer (score 0):

I Got little bit of solution of my own question. Here is Solution what I got.

```
class Line {
    float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
    public Line(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.startY = startY;
        this.stopX = stopX;
        this.stopY = stopY;
    }
    public Line(float startX, float startY) { // for convenience
        this(startX, startY, startX, startY);
    }
}

public class DrawView extends View {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    private void init() {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);

        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        textPaint.setTextSize(18 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    private void drawArrow1(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Canvas canvas, Paint paint1) {
        double degree = calculateDegree(startX, stopX, startY, stopY, canvas);
        float line_lenghtt = (float) Math.pow(Math.abs(startX-stopX),2) + (float) Math.pow(Math.abs(startY-stopY),2);
        line_lenghtt = (float) Math.sqrt(line_lenghtt);
        float inch = (float) (line_lenghtt / 95.999999998601);

        float m = (startX+stopX)/2;
        float m1 = (startY+stopY)/2;
        canvas.drawText(String.format("%.2f", inch)+"″",m,m1,textPaint);

        float endX1 = (float) (stopX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree-30)+90))));
        float endY1 = (float) (stopY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree-30)+90)))));

        float endX2 = (float) (stopX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree-60)+180))));
        float endY2 = (float) (stopY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree-60)+180)))));

        canvas.drawLine(stopX,stopY,endX1,endY1,paint1);
        canvas.drawLine(stopX, stopY, endX2,endY2,paint1);

    }

    private void drawArrow(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Canvas canvas, Paint paint1) {

        double degree1 = calculateDegree(stopX, startX, stopY, startY,canvas);
        float endX11 = (float) (startX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree1-30)+90))));
        float endY11 = (float) (startY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree1-30)+90)))));

        float endX22 = (float) (startX + ((20) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians((degree1-60)+180))));
        float endY22 = (float) (startY + ((20) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(((degree1-60)+180)))));

        canvas.drawLine(startX,startY,endX11,endY11,paint1);
        canvas.drawLine(startX,startY,endX22,endY22,paint1);
    }

    public double calculateDegree(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, Canvas canvas) {
        float startRadians = (float) Math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
        System.out.println("radian=====" + Math.toDegrees(startRadians));
        startRadians += ((x2 >= x1) ? 90 : -90) * Math.PI / 180;
        return Math.toDegrees(startRadians);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Line l : lines) {
            canvas.drawLine(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY, paint);
            drawArrow(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY,canvas,paint);
            drawArrow1(l.startX, l.startY, l.stopX, l.stopY,canvas,paint);
        }
    }

    float first_x, first_y, last_x, last_y, line_lenght;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            first_x = x;
            first_y = y;

            lines.add(new Line(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            return true;
        }
        else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) &&
                lines.size() > 0) {
            Line current = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
            current.stopX = event.getX();
            current.stopY = event.getY();
            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            line_lenght = (float) Math.pow(Math.abs(first_x-last_x),2) + (float) Math.pow(Math.abs(first_y-last_y),2);
            line_lenght = (float) Math.sqrt(line_lenght);
            Log.i("lenght", String.valueOf(line_lenght));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```